# What is the difference between sCMOS and CMOS?

Tags: cmos, image-sensor

I am interested in microscopy applications, and am looking at both sCMOS and CMOS sensors as options.

Why are sCMOS sensors so expensive compared to CMOS sensors?  What are the benefits, and are they really worth the extra cost?

Comment: Did you consider googling this? It looks like sCMOS sensors are just specifically manufactured to overcome some of the limitations of conventional CMOS sensors, specifically for use in scientific applications (the "s" in sCMOS).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this link [here](http://www.scmos.com/) for the fine details.

> > **Scientific CMOS (sCMOS)**
>
> Unlike previous generations of CMOS and CCD-based sensors, sCMOS is
>   uniquely capable of simultaneously offering:
>
> Extremely low noise
>  Rapid frame rates
>  Wide dynamic
>   range
>  High quantum efficiency (QE)
>  High resolution
>   Large field of view
>
> **Performance highlights of the first sCMOS technology sensor include:**
>  Sensor format: 5.5 megapixels (2560(h) x 2160(v))
>   Read noise: < 2 e- rms @ 30 frames/s; < 3 e- rms @ 100 frames/s
>   Maximum frame rate: 100 frames/s
>  Pixel size: 6.5 μm
>   Dynamic range: > 16,000:1 (@ 30 frames/s)
>  QEmax: 60% (with
>   excellent red/NIR response)

For more information than is practical to copy or write use the link provided. The benefits are listed above, and the high cost is obvious. It is the new kid on the block so mass consumption has not yet driven prices down. 
As the name implies, for the time being mostly scientist will be using this sCMOS sensor. Camera manufactures will have it in their best high-end cameras. They are worth the cost if you have the budget for them. Give it ten years and the cost will be much lower.

Comment: In other words: coming to your cellphone in 15 years or so :)